# Node.js - How to add timestamp to logs using Winston library?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I want to add timestamp to logs.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: This remains too broad because you canNOT do it from the client machine.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I was dealing with the same issue myself.  There are two ways I was able to do this.

When you include Winston, it usually defaults to adding a Console transport.  In order to get timestamps to work in this default case, I needed to either:

1. Remove the console transport and add again with the timestamp option.
2. Create your own Logger object with the timestamp option set to true.

The first:

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
winston.add(winston.transports.Console, {'timestamp':true});
```

The second, and cleaner option:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)({'timestamp':true})
    ]
});
```

Some of the other options for Console transport can be found [here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#console-transport):

- level: Level of messages that this transport should log (default 'debug').
- silent: Boolean flag indicating whether to suppress output (default false).
- colorize: Boolean flag indicating if we should colorize output (default false).
- timestamp: Boolean flag indicating if we should prepend output with timestamps (default false). If function is specified, its return value will be used instead of timestamps.

Comment: This is great. I usually wrap this in a dedicated file so that I can easily get my configured logger from any file, i.e., I put the above code (option 2) in a new file logger.js, followed by module.exports = logger; then from any file I do var logger = require('./logger.js') and can then do logger.info('hello') from any file and get the same configuration of Winston.

Comment: TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function

Comment: This does not appear to work in the current version of Winston. Try one of the other answers instead.

Answer (score 144):

Above answers did not work for me. In case you are trying to add timestamp to your logs using the latest version of Winston - 3.0.0-rc1, this worked like charm:

```
    const {transports, createLogger, format} = require('winston');

    const logger = createLogger({
        format: format.combine(
            format.timestamp(),
            format.json()
        ),
        transports: [
            new transports.Console(),
            new transports.File({filename: 'logs/error/error.log', level: 'error'}),
            new transports.File({filename: 'logs/activity/activity.log', level:'info'})
        ]
    });
```

I used 'format.combine()'. Since I needed timestamp on all my transports, I added the formatting option within the createLogger, rather than inside each transport. My output on console and on file (activity.log) are as follows:

```
{"message":"Connected to mongodb","level":"info","timestamp":"2018-02-01T22:35:27.758Z"}
{"message":"Connected to mongodb","level":"info","timestamp":"2018-02-01T22:35:27.758Z"}
```

We can add formatting to this timestamp in 'format.combine()' as usual using:

```
format.timestamp({format:'MM-YY-DD'})
```

Comment: Note that `format.timestamp` **has** to come before `format.json` (if you're using that latter)

Comment: @marvinIsSacul not true, I have them swapped and it works anyway!

Comment: mhhh alright @OtaconKiko not sure why it didn't on my side :think

Answer (score 36):

We can do like this also

```js
var winston = require('winston');
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
var config = require('../configurations/envconfig.js');

var loggerLevel = process.env.LOGGERLEVEL ||  config.get('LOGGERLEVEL');

var logger = winston.createLogger({
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`+(info.splat!==undefined?`${info.splat}`:" "))
  ),
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: loggerLevel }),
  ]
});
module.exports = logger;
```

Comment: Does this also work for `logger.info('Message', someObject)`? I setup a custom format using combine and I can't seem to get the `someObject` included in the log message.

Comment: I was able to get `someObject` included by using the following printf statement `${info.timestamp} [${info.level.toUpperCase()}]: ${info.message} ${JSON.stringify(info)}`. It includes the level, timestamp and message which I guess I could delete.

Answer (score 10):

You can use built-in [util](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html) and [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) to achieve logging with timestap for your nodejs server.
When you start a server add log output as part of the parameter:

```
forever start -ao log/out.log server.js
```

And then you can write util in your server.js

**server.js**

```
var util = require('util');
util.log("something with timestamp");
```

The output will look something like this to out.log file:

**out.log**

```
15 Mar 15:09:28 - something with timestamp
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `util.error()` skips timestamping the output.

Answer (score 7):

I took Biswadev's answer and created a stringified JSON object. This way if i need to process the logs later it will be in a well structured format.

```
const winston = require('winston');
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

var logger = createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        }),
        format.printf((info) =>
            JSON.stringify({
                t: info.timestamp,
                l: info.level,
                m: info.message,
                s: info.splat !== undefined ? `${info.splat}` : '',
            }) + ','
        )
    ),
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'PRODUCTION') {
    logger.add(new transports.Console({ format: winston.format.cli() }));

    // Turn these on to create logs as if it were production
    // logger.add(new transports.File({ filename: 'log/output/error.log', level: 'error' }));
    // logger.add(new transports.File({ filename: 'log/output/warn.log', level: 'warn' }));
    // logger.add(new transports.File({ filename: 'log/output/info.log', level: 'info' }));
} else {
    logger.add(new transports.File({ filename: 'log/output/error.log', level: 'error' }));
    logger.add(new transports.File({ filename: 'log/output/warn.log', level: 'warn' }));
    logger.add(new transports.File({ filename: 'log/output/info.log', level: 'info' }));
}

module.exports = {
    logger,
};
```

**Usage:**

```
app.listen(port, () => logger.info(`app is running on port ${port}`));
```

**Output:**

info.log file:

```
{"t":"2020-08-06 08:02:05","l":"info","m":"app is running on port 3001","s":""},
```

Console:

```
info:    app is running on port 3001
```

Comment: love that... copy paste solution !!

Comment: perfect one thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

Although I'm not aware of winston, this is a suggestion. I use [log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node) for logging & my logs by default look like this

```
[2012-04-23 16:36:02.965] [INFO] Development - Node Application is running on port 8090
[2012-04-23 16:36:02.966] [FATAL] Development - Connection Terminated to  '127.0.0.1' '6379'
```

Development is the environment of my node process & [INFO|FATAL] is log level

Maintaining different profiles for logging is possible in log4js. I have Development & Production profiles. Also there are logger types like rolling file appender, console appender, etc. As a addon your log files will be colorful based on the log level [Trace, Info, Debug, Error, Fatal] ;)

<strike>log4js will override your console.log</strike> It is a configurable parameter now in 0.5+

Comment: FYI: Newer versions of log4js-node (0.5+) don't automatically override console.log.

Comment: @jeffhiltz Ya you are right :) Now it is a configurable parameter

Answer (score 4):

we could use console-stamp to add timestamp and log level to the existing console: `require('console-stamp')(console, '[yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss.l]')`

See https://github.com/starak/node-console-stamp for the details

Comment: Except it does not add timestamp to File transports.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes default timestamp format can be not convenient for you.
You can override it with your implementation.

Instead of

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
  new (winston.transports.Console)({'timestamp':true})
]
});
```

you can write

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
  new (winston.transports.Console)({
     'timestamp': function() {
        return <write your custom formatted date here>;
     }
  })
]
});
```

See https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#custom-log-format for the details

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is wrapping the logger into a file that exports some functions like logger.info(), logger.error(), etc. then you just pass an extra key to be sent on every message log.

loggerService.js

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({ ... })

function handleLog(message, level) {
  const logData = {
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    message,
  }

  return logger[level](logData)
}

function info(message) {
  handleLog(message, 'info')
}

function error(message) {
  handleLog(message, 'error')
}

function warn(message) {
  handleLog(message, 'warn')
}

module.exports = {
  info,
  error,
  warn
}
```

whatever-file.js

```
const logger = require('./services/loggerService')

logger.info('Hello World!')
```

your-log.log

```
{"timestamp":"2019-08-21 06:42:27","message":"Hello World!","level":"info"}
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents which combine text console log with date time and color
(a mix of all previous answers plus [betterstack](https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/how-to-install-setup-and-use-winston-and-morgan-to-log-node-js-applications/) sample)

```js
import winston from "winston";
const format = winston.format;
const consoleTransport = new winston.transports.Console({
    "format": format.combine(
        format.colorize({ message: true }),
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'
        }),
        format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} | ${info.level.padEnd(5)} | ${info.message}`+(info.splat!==undefined?`${info.splat}`:" "))
    )
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({ transports: [consoleTransport] });

logger.error("Something bad happened.");
logger.info('oo - last ONE');
```

Limitations: if you colorize `all: true` or `level: true` then the padEnd on level is not applied. If you use `format.align()`, this align only the message start part..

Result:
[image: console output example with this custom format]

Answer (score 0):

For my project in logs needs timestamp as EpochTimeStamp. Here partial of winston options:

```
format: format.combine(
          format.timestamp({
            format: () => Date.now().toString(),
          }),
          format.errors({ stack: true }),
          format.splat(),
          format.json()
        ),
```

now all log contain ts

```
{"level":"info","message":"test","timestamp":"1707564604659"}
```