# No entries in log file when using logging library

Tags: node.js, winston

I do not know exactly if this is a issue resolving around forever or the libraries I tried but maybe someone can help here.

I was using console.log() through my application (express) to write logs. Now I've switched to a more feature packed logging library, namely Winston.js. Configured winston like this:

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
winston.add(winston.transports.Console, {timestamp: true});
```

and replaced my console.log() entries with winston.info/winston.error, you name it. After I launched my app with node app.js everything went as expected. So I tried to run it with forever, since in production I run it that way.

Now I encountered the problem that the whole log file from forever, using just forever start app.js, was empty. Not a single log entry was there.
I replaced winston with log4js, but the log file remained empty when launching it with forever.

Is there anything I am missing right now and if so where is the problem?

Sincerly,
cschaeffler

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271373/how-can-i-add-timestamp-to-logs-using-node-js-library-winston

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you simply kept the `Console` transport without adding a transport for a file, e.g.,

```
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'somefile.log' });
```

Comment: actually forever should take the console output and write it to a file. at least it works with normal console.log()

Comment: Did you try adding a `File` transport for winston?

Comment: Not yet, will as soon as i got time for that. However, forever assigns random filenames...