# How to add timestamp to winston saved log file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

This is my winston config file :

```
import winston from "winston";

const alignColorsAndTime = winston.format.combine(
  winston.format.colorize({
    all: true,
  }),
  winston.format.label({
    label: "[LOGGER]",
  }),
  winston.format.timestamp({
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
  }),
  winston.format.printf(
    (info) => `${info.label} ${info.timestamp} ${info.level} : ${info.message}`
  )
);

export const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: "debug",
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize(),
        alignColorsAndTime
      ),
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: "logs/example.log",
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp({
          format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        })
      ),
    }),
  ],
});
```

It logs like this :
[image]

The problem is the saved log file doesn't have timestamp :

```
{"level":"info","message":"asd"}
```

How can I add timestamp to the saved log file by winston ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `format.json()` to the combine?

Comment: I think this answer could help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271373/how-can-i-add-timestamp-to-logs-using-node-js-library-winston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with formats.json() like this :

```
export const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: "debug",
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize(),
        alignColorsAndTime
      ),
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: "logs/example.log",
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp({
          format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        }),
        winston.format.json()
      ),
    }),
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
winston.format.printf(
  (info) => `${info.label} [${new Date(info.timestamp).toISOString()}] 
    ${info.level} : ${info.message}`
)
```

Here you go, it will produce output like this.[image]

Comment: My question is How can I add timestamp to the generated log file . It doesn't solve the problem